# How do I replace one character with another but ONLY in href?

Tags: html, href

I have hundreds of links in below format:

```
a href="../Lorem_ipsum__"  title="Dolor_sit amet" target="__blank"
```

I need to change the `_` (underscore) character to `-` (hyphen), but ONLY in `href` (`title` and `target` need to remain unchanged).

I tried to do it with Dreamweaver's 'Find and Replace', but didn't succeed.

Comment: You need to create a regular expression find & replace in Dreamweaver.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is that I do not know how to create that...  :-(

Comment: thank you 'honk' in helping me in editing this post.

Comment: Check out a tutorial on regular expressions, and then look at a tutorial on how to use them in Dreamweaver's find & replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tick "Use regular expression" in Find and Replace, then search for:

```
(href="[^_"]*)_+([^"]*)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1-$2
```

The first parenthesis group searches for anything that starts with `href="`, then all characters except `_` or `"`.

Then we have the `_` one or more times.

The second parenthesis group searches for anything and stops before the closing `"`

You can then use the groups with `$1` and `$2` in Replace.

Here's an interactive tutorial if you want to learn regular expressions (regex): http://regexone.com/

Comment: is it possible to include rule to stop search after second "(or. '), i.e. to seach only inside (href="....") (and stop search here)?  Thank you.

Comment: also, pls let me know where can I upvote and accept the answer (I am new here...)

Comment: @Alex96 Next to my answer, press the tick and up arrow :)

Comment: I was trying to add $"|' but still did not stop only in href (in order to search onlyy between "........ " of the href.

Comment: (href=["|'][^_]+[$"|'])_([^"|']+)     ---unfortunately ng

Comment: yes, I did exactly how You recommend it, but search did not stop at the second " (the end of href) but continous also in "target" and / or "title".

Comment: @Alex96 It definitely works in Notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). You could try this: `(href="[^_]+)_([^"]+)` or read more on Dreamweaver's regex here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html

Comment: thank you!                                                         now seems to work well, but, unfortunatelly also replace the '_' where not should, in ex.                               a href="#top"><img src="../images/flow_up.gif"

Comment: @Alex96 Ah, in that case you will need to use `(href="[^_"]+)_([^"]+)`

Comment: Yesss!! That's the RIGHT ONE !!  THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I am very greatful for your kind help. Million thanks !!

Comment: @Alex96 Sorry, one more change: `(href="[^_"]*)_+([^"]*)` in case your href starts or ends with `_`.

Comment: @Alex96 Note that `_+` will replace one or more underscores with one dash. If you would rather only replace one underscore with one dash, you need to change it to `_{1}`.

Comment: THANK YOU very much again, I can not tell you how greatful I am for your help and support. THANK YOU!

Comment: Yes, indeed, mostly of my href end with _ or __.  Only one question: in some of my hrefs are more than one (sometimes even 3-4 underscores _.  Would it be possible to replace them all at once (now replaces only one -start from first- and must repet it to replace second one, etc. ?

Comment: And one other question / request: I have several hrefs ended with double __. I used     (href="[^_"]*)_+([^"]*) on Find and   $1-$2   on Replace.             When replacing, its replace from  the end the two "__" with only one "-".  Can be adjusted to change both __ into both --  ?  Thank you and I apologize for asking you for further help.

Comment: @Alex96 I don't know how you would replace more than one inside the href if they're separated. However, this is something that you can just keep running until there are no matches. And then you shouldn't need this regex again. If you have this much content, you should consider using PHP and MySQL, or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the regex file what you mentioned and try to understand, but unfortunatelly still can not succeed to figure out how its working. Your code is working well (Thank you again for it!) just if I have two undrescore __ at the end of href, it will replace with only one hyphens-. I try to modify your code according to the page/link you sent, but still could not resolved the problem. Anyhow, thank you very much again, and sorry that I bothered you with it. I am very grateful also, and if I can return somehow your help I will gladly do it. Thank you.